# Reconnect to same Zookeeper server with session id fails

Tags: apache-zookeeper

My client application connects to a Zookeeper server and creates an Ephemeral node:

```
    ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper(hostUrl, 40000, null);
    if (zk != null) {
        try {
            zk.create(zpath, "Test Node".getBytes(), 
                    ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
        } catch (KeeperException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If my client application crashes and restarts within session timeout period, I want to reconnect to the same Zookeeper server with the session id received from the previous session:

```
    ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper(hostUrl, 40000, null, previoudSessionId, null);
```

However, when I try to do this I always get a session expired exception:

```
12:20:26.737 [main-SendThread(172.20.34.24:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server 172.20.34.24/172.20.34.24:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
12:20:26.737 [main-SendThread(172.20.34.24:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.20.34.57:50462, server: 172.20.34.24/172.20.34.24:2181
12:20:26.737 [main-SendThread(172.20.34.24:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment request sent on 172.20.34.24/172.20.34.24:2181
12:20:26.737 [main-SendThread(172.20.34.24:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to reconnect to ZooKeeper service, session 0x157ff4a59300008 has expired, closing socket connection
12:20:26.747 [main-EventThread] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Error while calling watcher 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:553) [zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha.jar:3.5.1-alpha-1693007]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:528) [zookeeper-3.5.1-alpha.jar:3.5.1-alpha-1693007]
12:20:26.747 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down for session: 0x157ff4a59300008
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /Ephemeral
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:131)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:1209)
    at curatorExp.ZookeeperExp.reconnectWithSessionId(ZookeeperExp.java:53)
    at curatorExp.ZookeeperExp.main(ZookeeperExp.java:24)
```

Even after getting this exception, if I check the Zookeeper server using shell, I could see the ephemeral node that was created before the crash. (I have ensured that I am reconnecting before the session timeout of 40 seconds)

Is this expected to work?

Comment: Could be related to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2919